# Can't set permissions for a user as admin to run a program?

Tags: windows-10, security, permissions

Using windows 10.  Have a program TOP Server 6, a UPC-OA program, that I want a user called `Operator` to be able to run.  This user is part of the user group `Users`.  Under the server_config.exe (the program to run) Security tab, the group `Users` is there, and it has Full Contorl/Modify/Read & execute/Read/Write all checked off, however Read & Execute/Read are grey check marks.

I think the grey check marks mean these permissions are inherited.  When I click Advanced and see the Inheritance list, I see that the `Users` user group appears twice (among other entries and users).

First one I see -

```
Type        Principal                                  Access             Inherited From
============================================================= 
Allow       ALL APPLICATION PROGRAMS                   Full Control       None
Allow       Users (HostName\Users)                     Full Control       None
Allow       SYSTEM                                     Full control       C:\Program Files (x86)\
Allow       Administrators (HostName\Administrators)   Full control       C:\Program Files (x86)\
Allow       Users (HostName\Users)                     Read & Execute     C:\Program Files (x86)\
Allow       ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES                   Read & Execute     C:\Program Files (x86)\
Allow       ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES        Read & Execute     C:\Program Files (x86)\
```

If I double click on the first row with `Users (HostName\Users)` I see Basic Permissions with Full Control\Modify\Read & Execute\Read\Write checked off and they are editable by me.

If I double click the second row with `Users (HostName\Users)` everything is greyed out - Type Allow dropdown is unchangeable, FUll Contorl, Modify and Write are not checked and unable to be checked.  Read & Execute and Read are checked off and grey, unable to be modified.

I want the user `Operator` of users to be able to run this program.  What do I have to change here?  I am not sure what is going on here.

I have confirmed the `Operator` user is part of the `Users (HostName\Users)` group and I am logged in as the administrator currently.

Comment: In Properties of the executable, Security tab, click Advanced and then Effective Access. Select this user and then View effective access. Please add the screenshot of this window to your post.

Comment: Users only need `Read & execute` permissions to run software. The process of elevating a process (running-as-administrator) is very different from what you can do in the Security tab though. The user must be in the Administrators group (or have the credentials for a user who is). There are a couple options to make it easier like using an icon with saved creds: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/allow-standard-users-to-run-a-program-with-admin-rights

Comment: It turned out my permissions on the executable were fine.  What I needed to do which I found by googling permissions and the TOP Server 6 was to allow permissions on my `Users` user group for `C:\ProgramData\SoftwareTool Box` which I assume the application reads/writes to.  If I didn't find that post, would there be any way for me to tell that was the case via windows logs or someway else?  I found the answer here - https://support.softwaretoolbox.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3872/~/permissions-issues-when-accessing-the-top-server-6.7-configuration

Comment: @BrianKarabinchak there aren't many easy ways. If it's just fin. Process monitor can tell you what files get opened and/or written to. It's common for software to want to write to `C:\ProgramData\FolderX` or `C:\Program Files\FolderY` which requires admin permissions by default. There are other OS actions like trying to start/stop services that can be more difficult to hunt down, so it depends on the software and what it's doing

Comment: Ok thank you.  So Process monitor might help but I should always check the corresponding ProgramData folder first as that is very common.